# Breeze.js - foreign keys not cleared when deleting a new (EntityState = "Added") entity

Tags: breeze

I have noticed an irksome discrepancy in Breeze.js between deleting a not yet persisted entity (EntityState = "Added") and a persisted entity with respect to any references to it (foreign keys).

This may be an issue related to generating temporary keys for new entities. In this case, we generate negative numbers for temporary keys (ids), replaced with the actual keys when they are persisted.

This will be more easily explained with a concrete example. Say we have an entity called Person that holds a reference to a Title entity ("Mr", "Mrs", etc):

```
export class Person extends EntityBase {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    titleId: number;
    title: Title;
    ...
}

export class Title extends EntityBase {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    ...
}
```

Now, if we have a persisted Title entity in our current context and call .setDeleted() on it, both the titleId property and the title navigation property on applicable Person entities are set to null.

If, however, the Title entity has an EntityState of "Added", only the title navigation property on all linked Person entities is set to null. The titleId property retains its value, leading to an error when saving (a foreign key constraint violation).

This means that deleting a Title entity with an EntityState of "Added" requires explicitly setting the titleId property to null for all linked Person entities.

It is perhaps worth noting that the TitleID column in the underlying database is nullable. If it were not, we would, of course, have to set the titleId property to a suitable value.

It seems clumsy to have to do this. Is this behavior intentional, for some reason that escapes me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to deletes, Breeze makes an important distinction between

- **(case a)** entities that exist only on the client (those in the Added state), and
- **(case b)** entities that have been persisted on the server.

For an already-persisted entity **(case b)**, Breeze must keep track of that deleted entity,
and send the deletion to the server.  Any foreign keys on the server must be updated
to remove references to the deleted entity, so breeze updates the related client entities accordingly
and sends those changes to the server as well.

For a newly-created entity **(case a)**, the server knows nothing about it.  When it is
"deleted" on the client, Breeze doesn't actually set it `Deleted`, because it doesn't
need to send a deletion to the server.  Instead, it sets it `Detached`.

When an entity is set `Detached`, its navigation properties are set to null, and it
is removed from the EntityManager's cache.  Its foreign key properties are not changed,
however, so if you detach an entity and re-attach it, the navigation properties will
be reconnected.  This is true whether the entity was `Added` or any other state before
it became `Detached`.

More about the entity states can be found in the [Breeze documentation](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/inside-entity.html)

Comment: That makes sense when calling setDetached() on an entity with an EntityState of Added but when you call setDeleted() on an entity it is pretty unambiguous - you are saying you want it removed. Yes, behind the scenes Breeze just detaches it but leaving foreign keys that reference it seems sloppy to me. In what possible scenario would leaving these keys (that now reference an entity that will never exist) behind be useful?

Comment: I agree with @ToboldHornblower. Just treating deletes of added entities as detaches oversimplifies things a bit. If I am deleting then it is because I don't want that entity in the database. If the entity's record is not in the database then foreign keys that reference it are always going to have problems. The navigation properties upon which they are based should be cleaned up during the delete. Ideally breeze would look after that. In lieu of that, is there any way that we could manually handle that? Somehow hook into the logic that is used for deletes?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is actually a case where Breeze should be modified to handle deletes of `Added` entities a little more intelligently. In the meantime though, the following might represent a workaround (I have not had a chance to try it out so far).

Firstly for `Added` entities that are deleted, the problem seems to be that navigation properties which reference the entity do not get updated to remove these references. It might be possible to trick Breeze into looking after this.

1. First set the state of the added entity which is to be deleted to something like `Unchanged`.
2. Delete the entity. Because the state of the entity is no longer `Added`, the logic that translates the Delete into a Detach will not apply. The entity will have its state set to `Deleted` and navigation properties that reference it will be updated so that they no longer do.
3. Leaving the entity with a state of `Deleted` would be an issue as there would be an attempt to delete an entity that does not actually exist. Set its state to Detached to prevent this.

So instead of just deleting, try setting the state to `Unchanged`, then delete and finally set the state to `Detached`.